# Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app

Tags: node.js, heroku, webpack

I have mean stack node js app , I am trying to deploy it to heroku , unfortunatelly I am getting the following message.

```
remote:        Installing any new modules (package.json)
remote:        npm ERR! code EINVALIDTAGNAME
remote:        npm ERR! Invalid tag name "^6.0.0.beta.1": Tags may not have any characters that encodeURIComponent encodes.
remote:
remote:        npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
remote:        npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.3UQhB/_logs/2018-07-08T09_19_13_394Z-debug.log
remote:
remote: -----> Build failed
remote:
remote:        We're sorry this build is failing! You can troubleshoot common issues here:
remote:        https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys
remote:
remote:        Some possible problems:
remote:
remote:        - node_modules checked into source control
remote:        https://blog.heroku.com/node-habits-2016#9-only-git-the-important-bits
remote:
remote:        - Node version not specified in package.json
remote:        https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#specifying-a-node-js-version
remote:
remote:        Love,
remote:        Heroku
remote:
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app.
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
remote: !       Push rejected to proexebookingapp.
remote:
To https://git.heroku.com/proexebookingapp.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/proexebookingapp.git'

C:\Users\Bonge\Documents\Projects\bookinga

pp>
```

here is my package.json file

```
{
  "name": "movies-database",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "a simple movie database Rest API",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "nodemon server.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "Geofrey Julius Zellah",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.18.3",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "connect-flash": "^0.1.1",
    "cors": "^2.8.4",
    "express": "^4.16.3",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "mongodb": "^2.2.33",
    "mongoose": "^5.1.5",
    "node-rest-client": "^3.1.0",
    "nodemon": "^1.17.5",
    "request": "^2.87.0",
    "winston": "^3.0.0",
    "primeng": "^6.0.0.beta.1",
  "primeicons": "^1.0.0-beta.6"
  }
}
```

I tried different method from google but nothing helped, maybe some knows this problem in heroku deployment environment,

Please can some one help me on this?any help suggestion will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`^6.0.0.beta.1` isn't a valid semantic version, this is what error message says.

As [semantic versioning spec](https://semver.org/#spec-item-9) states,

> A pre-release version MAY be denoted by appending a hyphen and a series of dot separated identifiers immediately following the patch version. Identifiers MUST comprise only ASCII alphanumerics and hyphen [0-9A-Za-z-]. Identifiers MUST NOT be empty. Numeric identifiers MUST NOT include leading zeroes. Pre-release versions have a lower precedence than the associated normal version. A pre-release version indicates that the version is unstable and might not satisfy the intended compatibility requirements as denoted by its associated normal version. Examples: 1.0.0-alpha, 1.0.0-alpha.1, 1.0.0-0.3.7, 1.0.0-x.7.z.92.

There's already a proper beta version next to `primeng`,

```
"primeicons": "^1.0.0-beta.6"
```

It should be:

```
"primeng": "^6.0.0-beta.1",
```